# Live search with Vue + PHP

Tags: php, vue.js

I have a live search form and it works ok, but I want to add dropdown menu where I can choose DB in which I need to perform search. Tried many variant, but unsuccessful. As I undestand I need to add second parameter "selected" to axios post function that sends all requests to php file. Any idea please?

Here is my code:

JavaScript

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#myapp',
    data: {
        members: [],
                selected: "",
        search: {keyword: ''},
        noMember: false
    },

    mounted: function(){
        this.fetchMembers();
    },

    methods:{
        searchMonitor: function() {
            var keyword = app.toFormData(app.search);
            axios.post('action.php?action=search', keyword)
                .then(function(response){
                    app.members = response.data.members;

                    if(response.data.members == ''){
                        app.noMember = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        app.noMember = false;
                    }
                });
        },

        fetchMembers: function(){
            axios.post('action.php')
                .then(function(response){
                    app.members = response.data.members;
                });
        },

        toFormData: function(obj){
            var form_data = new FormData();
            for(var key in obj){
                form_data.append(key, obj[key]);
            }
            return form_data;
        },

    }
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="myapp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                    <h3>
                        <select  data-style="btn-info" v-model="selected">
                            <option selected="selected" value="1">Search in both DB</option>
                            <option  value="2">Search in DB1</option>
                            <option  value="3">Search in DB2</option>
                        </select>
                    </h3>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" v-on:keyup="searchMonitor" v-model="search.keyword">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-if="noMember">
                        <td colspan="3" align="center">No member match your search</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-for="member in members">
                        <td>{{ member.first_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ member.last_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "vuetot");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$out = array('error' => false);

$action="show";

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action=$_GET['action'];
}

if($action=='show'){
    $sql = "select * from members";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $members = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
        array_push($members, $row);
    }

    $out['members'] = $members;
}

if($action=='search'){
    $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
    $sql="select * from members where first_name like '%$keyword%' or last_name like '%$keyword%' or email like '%$keyword%'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $members = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
        array_push($members, $row);
    }

    $out['members'] = $members;
}

$conn->close();

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($out);
die();

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: An other warning : you should not login as root with your web app. Even for development since you'll need to test the permissions at some point anyway.

Comment: @Seblor - Why would that matter in a local dev-environment as long as they create a user with the correct permissions in production? On any publicly accessible site, I would agree though.

Comment: From an other comment elsewhere : "Never get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes, so if your app has any vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually needs in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup"

Comment: It just a sample login credentials!

Comment: Even if it is for testing purpose only, database security should never be left aside, or you will be used to bad practices.

Comment: the problem is you'll forget. Like Equifax, you will likely expose users' information because the data is siloed and not secure. Implementing security as an after-thought is dangerous, and when handling other people's personal information, careless.